# Objective C: “Property implementation must have its declaration in interface”

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I keep getting error above but I am not sure why. I imported all the required classes and I declared the properties. Any help is appreciated. I have included code below:

```
//  NewModuleViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewModuleViewController : UIViewController {

    UITextField *textModuleCode;
    UITextField *textModuleTitle;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textModuleCode;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textModuelTitle;
@end



//  NewModuleViewController.m

#import "NewModuleViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface NewModuleViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewModuleViewController
@synthesize textModuleCode, textModuleTitle;
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you wrote `textModuelTitle` instead of `textModuleTitle` in your `.h`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, silly omission indeed

Comment: Your welcome, it happens sometimes. You should enter the first letters of the property and let xcode proposes you the end (autocompletion). Accept the answer if it is ok for you. Thanks